# Set AA AF for OpenGL game, using amdgpu xorg driver

Tags: opengl, amdgpu

Since we have no control panel for xorg amdgpu driver, how to set any anti-aliasing options for games that don't have menu choices for it? Does the amdgpu driver honour OpenGL environment variables that nvidia driver does?
I'm specifically after FSAA and anisotropic antialiasing.